# Java: SQLSyntaxErrorException at the ? symbol

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following line of code that I am trying to execute:

```
List<File> sectList = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM legaf WHERE ida = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setInt(1, idforfile);
        ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next())
        {
            fls.add(result.getInt("idf"));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I receive the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

which points at the following statement:

```
ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery(query);
```

I am trying to apply the query to a XAMPP MySQL database. I am using Intellij.
fls is declared as

```
private List<Integer> fls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Is `ida` a number type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

```
preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```

and not

```
preparedStmt.executeQuery(query);
```

else you are executing `Statement.executeQuery(String)` which does not resolve parameters in the query string.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass in the query string to `executeQuery()`.

Change this:

```
ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery(query);
```

to this:

```
ResultSet result = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```

Primary offenders among tutorials promoting passing in the query string is MkYong:

https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Here we find the following line:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```